# problem integrating silverlight toolkit in VS2010 project

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

i've installed silverlight toolkit from codeplex (NuGet didn't work, feed was empty.. probably working on the project) and after referencing

> Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit

I get the error :

> The type or namespace name 'Toolkit' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft.Phone.Controls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

What could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your xmlns is calling it `toolbox` but the prefix is `toolkit`.

Change

```
xmlns:toolbox="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

to

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

Or, change your prefix to `toolbox`. It doesn't matter what you call it; it just has to be consistent.

Comment: tnx for the reply! the problem though is not fixed, i get an error "The type or namespace name 'Toolkit' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Phone.Controls' (are you missing an assembly reference?)".

Comment: It's case sensitive - so if the control's prefix is `toolkit`, `Toolkit` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

In this line you declare toolbox as a name to reference the toolkit

```
xmlns:toolbox="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

In this line you reference to the name toolkit

```
<toolkit:DatePicker Header="Date" Value="9/16/2010" ValueChanged="DatePickerValueChanged"/>
```

It does not work because those names should be equal. So either declare xmlns:toolkit or reference toolbox:DatePicker

Good luck!